# tomahawk t:inputFileUpload not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, tomahawk

I have developed a jsf application with following facets

- Dynamic Web Module 2.5
- Java 5
- JavaServer Faces 1.2
- Rich Faces 3.3.2

I have a page with an t:inputFileUpload component. it was working fine till i added ajax and rich faces components and taglibs to my page. As follows:-

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
...
<t:inputFileUpload...
```

All i want to ask is that, is it not possible that these taglibs can work together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work fine as long as you don't submit the form by ajax. It's namely not possible to upload files by ajax using the `<t:inputFileUpload>`. So, you need to make sure that you submit the form by a synchronous (non-ajax) request.

You should also make sure that the Tomahawk's `ExtensionsFilter` is been registered in `web.xml` *before* RichFaces' `org.ajax4jsf.Filter`, otherwise it will consume the `multipart/form-data` request before Tomahawk's `ExtensionsFilter` get chance to do so.

Alternatively, you could drop Tomahawk's `<t:inputFileUpload>` and use RichFaces' own `<rich:fileUpload>` instead. It's able to simulate a "ajax look-a-like" file upload using Flash.

Comment: yes sir, i am using a4j:support in the selectOneMenu and submitting on change..any how. now i m gona do some thing about it in the light of ur guidance.

Comment: @BalusC as a matter of curiosity, why does it not work when using ajax?

Comment: @jwa: Because `XMLHttpRequest` level 1 (as used by ajax4jsf) doesn't support `multipart/form-data` encoding, which is mandatory in order to be able to send files via a HTTP request.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that you have an "encrypeType" in your form.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully. It says *"it was working fine till i added ajax and rich faces components and taglibs to my page"*. If the OP didn't use the proper `enctype`, it would impossibly have worked fine before.